# App Widget does not receive onEnabled and onDisabled broadcasts on HTC One X

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an app widget that has been working successfully on many different devices. It relies on the onEnabled and onDisabled methods. Recent testing has shown that these methods were not being called on the new HTC One X.

Due to the complexity of my app widget, I wrote a very simple app widget that just displays a static image. All it does other than that, is output to the log when onEnabled and onDisabled is called. When this is tested on the emulator and other devices, it works fine. But on the HTC One X, no output is observed for either case.

Does anyone know of a possible reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not good. Can you post that sample project somewhere? I'd like to take a peek at it and possibly get it to some HTC folk for review.

Comment: Hi. I've uploaded to Google docs here https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxB1b2zoeWRgdzVnT3dyb3I1TWs (not used that before so not sure if that's an ok method). It's a simple project, but it's written in Netbeans and not Eclipse. I'm not a fan of Eclipse I'm afraid. Thanks.

Comment: That's interesting -- I had no idea Google Docs could handle a ZIP file. I will take a peek at this later today.

Comment: Your code seems to work. I'll try to pass this along to HTC for investigation. In the meantime, if you have the time and inclination, try replacing the home screen with a third-party implementation and see if there is an effect. Thanks!